# target [Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\RegisterViewResponse] is not instantiable

Tags: php, laravel, fortify

i'm have a router register but i found error

Target [Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\RegisterViewResponse] is not instantiable.

Comment: Could you please provide some code explaining what you're doing? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to register fortify service provider inside the `config/app.php` files

Add this

```
App\Providers\FortifyServiceProvider::class,
```

to `config/app.php` under the Application's Service Providers.

**Update :** It is also important you point the location of your authentication views to Fortify.

An example for the Register view would be:

```php
//  auth.register => means your register.blade is located in `view/auth/`
//  folder. (All things being equal)

Fortify::registerView(function () {
    return view('auth.register');
});
```

Read More: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/fortify#registration

Comment: Added, but not resolved

Comment: @realtebo you have to let fortify know the location of your auth files. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/fortify#registration

Comment: After doing the above step if it not work then try this `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: Is there a way to skip `registerView()` for json api based backends? I'd just like to have the fortify api, but don't want to implement frontend views.

Comment: @NicoHood Yes, you can. Go to your `fortify.php` config and set view to false. `'views' => false,` and be sure to use the `api.php` route file for your routes.

Comment: @JosephAjibodu Thanks! Is there a way to tell fortify to use the api routes? I mean they are automatically added as e.g. `/register`. Also currently I get `CSRF token mismatch.` which I have to solve first. Any ideas?

Comment: @NicoHood To access any route created in the api.php file, all you have to do is append `/api/<route>` to your urls. e.g `/user` will now be `/api/user`. As regards the CSRF token, do you use sanctum? If yes, are you using `cookie session` for authentication or `API token`?
>>>>>
If you are using `API token` go to `app/Http/Kernel.php`, make sure this line of code is not there `\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
    'throttle:api',`. If it is there, remove it or uncomment it, you don't need sanctum's middleware for `API token` authentication.

Comment: @NicoHood But if you are using Sanctum Stateful Authentication,  ensure both your backend and frontend are on the same `tld` or both running on `localhost`. Set `SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost` and `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost:3000`.

Check this out for more info, https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#spa-authenticating

Comment: Now I am quite confused. I do want to use the API tokens. What does this middleware do and why do I have to disable it? Is foritfy even useful, if I want to write a pure REST api? I cannot find much information on api only laravel apps online, so if you got any detailed tips, I'd be happy. Thanks!

Comment: The middleware protects your routes from CSRF attacks. That is why you the error `CSRF token mismatch. So you only need it when you are using Cookie Based Authentication.

Fortify is a package for authentication and it fits well for an API since it's a backend authentication system, it doesn't really on the frontend to work.

If you intend to use API tokens, I'd believe you are using Sanctum for generating API tokens.

Once you have those two installed. You log a user in by generating API token for the user, a log them out by revoking the API token.

Comment: I compiled a quick article that could help, check it out https://medium.com/@josephajibodu/laravel-basic-api-with-token-authentication-1ca435873b6f

Answer (score 8):

you have to add all these in **FortifyServiceProvider.php** at the **boot** method.
then import all classes needed

```
Fortify::loginView(function(){
            return view('auth.login');
        });

        Fortify::authenticateUsing(function(Request $request){
            $user = User::where('email',$request->email)->first();
            if($user && Hash::check($request->password,$user->password)){
                return $user;
            }
        });
         Fortify::registerView(function(){
            return view('auth.register');
        });
```

after that you need to create the **register** and **login** view

Comment: clearly and short! thanks talhaouycoding!

Comment: Note: this is when you are not using one of Laravels starter kits like Jetstream or Breeze

Answer (score 5):

Verify that the following providers are registered in the `config.app` file in the `providers` section

```php
App\Providers\FortifyServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\JetstreamServiceProvider::class, // If using Jetstream
```

Uncomment the following line in the `App\Providers\FortifyServiceProvider.php` file

```php
Fortify::createUsersUsing(CreateNewUser::class);
```

Answer (score 2):

Make registerView function on app/providers/FortifyServiceProvider.php

```
    Fortify::registerView(function () {
        return view('auth.register');
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Joseph Ajibodu's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14938599/joseph-ajibodu) answer, within the boot method of `FortifyServiceProvider` add the following:

```
    Fortify::loginView(function () {
        return view('auth.login');
    });

    Fortify::registerView(function () {
        return view('auth.register');
    });

    Fortify::requestPasswordResetLinkView(function () {
        return view('auth.forgot-password');
    });

    Fortify::resetPasswordView(function () {
        return view('auth.reset-password');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Fortify::registerView(function () {
return view('auth.register');

put this code in your fortyfive service provider  folder under the book method

Answer (score 0):

Description:
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target [Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginViewResponse] is not instantiable.

Steps To Reproduce:
Manjaro Linux 20.2.1

1.Create a new Laravel project

2.cd into the project, then composer require laravel/fortify

3.php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Fortify\FortifyServiceProvider"

4.Add App\Providers\FortifyServiceProvider::class to config\app.php

5.php artisan migrate

6.Create an auth folder in resources\views, then add a login.blade.php inside folder

7.In routes\web.php, add middleware('auth') to the route to the welcome page

8.php artisan serve

You need to add

Fortify::loginView(fn () => view('auth.login'));
To the boot method of FortifyServiceProvider.

See the [docs on authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/fortify#authentication)