# Target [Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\ResetsUserPasswords] is not instantiable

Tags: laravel, passwords, laravel-fortify

I am implementing the forgot password / password reset logic with Laravel 8 and Fortify for an SPA application.

When the /reset-password is called and if the data are all correct (email, password, password_confirmation, token), I get a server side error:

**Target [Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\ResetsUserPasswords] is not instantiable.**

The route is defined as follows in api.php:

```
Route::post('/reset-password', [NewPasswordController::class, 'store']);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: For those who have the same issue, I found the solution. Add this line in FortifyServiceProvider boot:

Fortify::resetUserPasswordsUsing(ResetUserPassword::class);

Comment: I am currently experiencing the same problem. Fortify::resetUserPasswordsUsing(ResetUserPassword::class); is already in my FortifyServiceProvider.

Answer (score 2):

**I had the same issue in my *API* and I was able to resolve it.**

*Target [Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\ResetsUserPasswords] is not instantiable.*

`Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\ResetsUserPasswords` is an interface, and Fortify (by default) has implemented the ResetsUserPassword Action which implements the interface.

All you need to get it working is to ensure this class `App\Providers\FortifyServiceProvider::class` is registered within the `providers` array of your application's `config/app.php` configuration file.

```php
// ...
App\Providers\FortifyServiceProvider::class,
```

Comment: Nice catch! I was wondering why it was not working and I missed the step to include the class in `providers` array

Answer (score -1):

You need to register views, thats why this error is throwing.  I was able to fix the issue by doing this.

Document: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/fortify#registration

Please check this thread: [target [Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\RegisterViewResponse] is not instantiable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66004083/target-laravel-fortify-contracts-registerviewresponse-is-not-instantiable)

```
Fortify::registerView(function () {
    return view('auth.register');
});
```